# Select Last PaymentDay

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables: `FightersInfo` and `PaymentInfo`. 1 fighter got many payment days. 
I need help to select last payment day.

```
SELECT FName, LName, PaymentDay, PaymentDescr,PaymentAmount, Active 
WHERE (PaymentAMount= 0 
       OR PaymentAmount = NULL 
       OR PaymentDay = NULL 
       OR "Last PaymentDay is before 1 month ago") 
AND Active =1
```

[image: HERE is my tables]

Comment: hmm, I don't get what you want. By the way change the = NULL => IS NULL

Comment: i think the expression for `Last PaymentDay is before 1 month ago`

Comment: nothing in you question explains what you mean "Select Last PaymentDay". Can you add an explanation.

Comment: i mean that a Fighter has many PaymentDays i want to Select only the last one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, you want to `INNER JOIN` those tables like this:

```
   SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
         pi.FighterId, 
         FName, 
         LName, 
         PaymentDay, 
         PaymentDescr,
         PaymentAmount, 
         Active,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fi.FighterId ORDER BY PaymentDay DESC) rn
    FROM 
      FightersInfo fi LEFT JOIN 
      PaymentInfo pi ON pi.FighterId = fi.FighterId
    WHERE 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PaymentInfo WHERE FighterId = fi.FighterId
                         AND DATEDIFF(month, PaymentDay, GETDATE()) = 0 )
      AND Active =1) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

All the conditions on amount are removed for readability.

Comment: i want only the last payment for one fighter  not all the payments thats before a month ...

Comment: i need a litle bit more help here ... this returns all the payments thats before a month ... i want to get only the Last payment of fighter if is before a month ...

For example if a fighter has many payments only before a month i want the last payment 

But if a fighter has a lot payments before a month and gots a payment in last month i dont want him in my select

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d861/1 here is my schema i want to return only the last PaymentDay of FighterID=1 Causes the FighterID=2 he paid in last month

Comment: That worked but i also need FighterID = 3 because he never Payed and he is not in PaymentInfo Table

Comment: Ok, you need to change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, i have updated the answer.

Comment: Bulat i want a litle bit more help ... this is ok for the PaymentDay if is a month before but i want to check if he payed 30 days ago ... 
i would appreciate if you could help me

Comment: @Kostaras  Try `DATEDIFF(day, PaymentDay, GETDATE()) <= 30`

Comment: Bulat last help on this please ... this SQL statement returns only the first person that he is not in PaymentInfo ... i want all of them ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` Operator here.
I think this will solve you problem,

```
SELECT FIGHTERID,FName, LName, Active , LastPayment.PaymentDay, LastPayment.PaymentDescr,LastPayment.PaymentAmount
    FROM FightersInfo fi 
    Outer Apply
        (
            Select top 1 PaymentDay, PaymentDescr,PaymentAmount 
                From PaymentInfo pi 
            Where pi.FighterId = fi.FighterId
            Order by PaymentDay desc
        ) as LastPayment  
    Where   Active =1  
    and  Isnull(DATEDIFF(month, LastPayment.PaymentDay, GETDATE()),1) > 0
```

Option2 : Just small change is where condition

```
SELECT FIGHTERID,FName, LName, Active , LastPayment.PaymentDay, LastPayment.PaymentDescr,LastPayment.PaymentAmount
    FROM FightersInfo fi 
    Outer Apply
        (
            Select top 1 PaymentDay, PaymentDescr,PaymentAmount 
                From PaymentInfo pi 
            Where pi.FighterId = fi.FighterId
            Order by PaymentDay desc
        ) as LastPayment  
    Where   Active =1  
    and  (
            DATEDIFF(month, LastPayment.PaymentDay, GETDATE()) > 0
            OR
            LastPayment.PaymentDay is null
          )
```

I didn't understand your logic of where conditions on PaymentInfo Table, But I have shown how you can select Top 1 / more / min / max record from related table using `CROSS APPLY`. Try to Google `APPLY operator`.

SQLFIDDLE DEMO [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d861/43)

Comment: i need a litle bit more help here ... this returns all the payments thats before a month ... i want to get only the Last payment of fighter if is before a month ...

For example if a fighter has many payments only before a month i want the last payment 

But if a fighter has a lot payments before a month and gots a payment in last month i dont want him in my select

Comment: I didn't understood you requirement.

Comment: a fighter has many PaymentDay  1/1/13 & 2/1/13 &....& 9/1/14 he has payed in last month i dont want his paymentDay in the select 

But if a fighter has PaymentDay  1/1/13 & 2/1/13 & ....& 8/1/14 i want the last payment day "8/1/14"

Comment: OK , I think I have got it. Please give me some time.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check it. I don't have schema of you data, so unable to TEST. Just modifying on fly. Please share schema on SQLFiddle.

Comment: I have EDITED answer. 1 Query If Last Payment was on '8/1/2014' then you want that fighter or not? Cause it was in Last month.

Comment: If that fighter has also a payment in last month I don't want him but if he hasn't payed in last month I want him

Comment: Pls try now, I have converted CROSS APPLY in OUTER APPLY.

Comment: If not, I would suggest you to Share schema with Data & Expected output with reasons, it would better to solve your query.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d861/1 here is my schema  i want to return only the last PaymentDay of FighterID=1 
Causes the FighterID=2 he paid in last month

Comment: I got solution for you. Answer updated with FIDDLE Demo also. Please check.

Comment: I hope you just want to avoid records who are made payment in Current month September (9), this is what seems in you fiddle. But you was always saying that you want to avoid who have paid in Last month (August), but in demo you have written that you want that record. So your question & comments were confusing me.

Comment: OK. you can do it later.